# Importing photos froze

Tags: lightroom

[image]

I am currently stuck at this dialog. I have tried re-importing but every time I ended up getting stuck.

Is there a way for Lightroom to log which file it's currently stuck at so I can go in and delete it manually?

(When I cancel, I don't always see a dialog LR showing which file it had difficulty importing).

1. This is without video files
2. I am not importing from an SD card. I am importing from my SSD hard disk to my LR catalog
3. I am using the latest version of LR on Mac

Comment: Have you try to optimize the catalog?

Comment: yes I have. No difference.

Comment: try to import the images on small batches to identify the problematic file.

Comment: i would assume the ninth file is the problematic one...

Comment: How would I know which is the ninth file?

Comment: Is your disk full? Is the source file system corrupt? Have you tried rebooting your computer?

Comment: No, No, Yes. Multiple times as well

Comment: @Tinker, how long did you wait the process? It happen to me sometime after import when build smart preview to "freeze" for 5 to 15 minutes .

Comment: I waited for 24 hours

Comment: In such case you may start to import them in small batches (10 photos for example) to easy find the problematic one.